# Gatsby Shadowing CSS file is not being reflected

Tags: gatsby

Im following [these instructions](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal/#changing-the-color-scheme) to change the color scheme of my project. However I don't see it working. This is the file in the module I am trying to shadow:

[image]

And this is my current file that I try to use to override the styles:

[image]

One thing that caught my attention is that if I am running my code with `gatsby develop` and I save one `pages/styles.css` gatsby deploys the file automatically but If I save the newest  `theme.css`, gatsby doesn't do the same.

Can someone tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Should the changes be reflected automatically after "shadowing" them or I need to build the project again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the theme author and [this issue](https://github.com/konstantinmuenster/gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal/issues/4), you are placing the theme.css in the correct path (`{project root}/src/gatsby-theme-portfolio-minimal/globalStyles/theme.css`) but it seems to be hard-cached.

Try running `gatsby clean` to clean up your cache and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using gatsby cli and you are using yarn can run `yarn clean` and restart your server